# How to deploy web application to WSO2-AS (cluster mode)

Tags: wso2, wso2-as

I followed the official guide to set up a cluster (Clustering AS 5.3.0) (https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Setting+up+a+Cluster).

But eventually, I could not reach the management page with https://localhost:9443/carbon, and the

Manager Node (10.13.46.34): (with some Error when passing date, i still dont know how to fix)
wso2server -Dsetup

```
[05-10 11:58:29]ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient}-Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue May 03 17:35:
14 CST 2016"
[05-10 12:01:04]INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.wka.WKABasedMembershipScheme}-Member joined [a9402117-a832-4eb6-b563-a58949ff784e]: /10.0.34.41:4200
[05-10 12:01:06]INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.util.MemberUtils}-Added member: Host:10.0.34.41, Remote Host:null, Port: 4200, HTTP:9763, HTTPS:9443, Domain: wso2.as.doma
in, Sub-domain:worker, Active:true
[05-10 12:03:31]INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}-'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-05-10 12:03:31,999+0800]
```

Worker node(10.0.34.44):
wso2server.bat -DworkerNode=true

```
......
......
[05-10 12:01:25]INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent}-Server           :Application Server-5.3.0
[05-10 12:01:25]INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent}-WSO2 Carbon started in 88 sec
[05-10 12:01:26]INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://10.0.34.44:9443/carbon/
[05-10 12:02:20]INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-05-10 12:02:20,817+0800]
```

i can successfully login Manager-node's mgt console ('https://10.13.46.34:9443/carbon/')

but fail to login Worker-node's mgt console (https://10.0.34.44:9443/carbon/)

So, anyone can tell me how Manager-node's console page to list out a set of application servers? because I want to manage all node together.
And how to deploy a web-application to all nodes in this AS cluster environment.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start the WSO2 AS node with -DworkerNode=true then you can't access the UI. Because normally worker nodes are use to serve the requests. therefore worker profile doesnt cantains ui features

According to your comment you are having a one manager node and one worker node. You can use deployment synchronizer to deploy webapps in worker nodes. Basically what is happening through that is when you deploy a webapp in the management node it will be commit to a svn location and worker node will checkout that. So worker node also get a copy of the app.
You can refer to https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+SVN-Based+Deployment+Synchronizer for more details and setup

Or simply you can copy the war file to the repository/deployment/server/webapp folder manually in the worker node.

Comment: thank you guy.
And do you know how to fix the following exception on Manager-Node?   

ERROR :      {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient}-Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue May 03 17:35:14 CST 2016"

Comment: That is a kinown bug https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-2977 you can apply the fix mentioned in the jira and create a patch for your self